# How to call ASP.NET Core Web API from Expo project

Tags: asp.net-core, expo, stripe-payments, asp.net-core-webapi

I have built a C# backend with functioning APIs that can retrieve data using Swagger, for example: `https://localhost:5001/api/NguoiDung`.

It returns this data:

```
[
  {
    "taiKhoan": "iu",
    "matKhau": "123",
    "hoVaTen": "",
    "tenHienThi": "",
    "soDienThoai": "",
    "ngaySinh": "2022-12-15T00:00:00",
    "soDu": 0,
    "chucVu": false
  },
  {
    "taiKhoan": "nhun",
    "matKhau": "123",
    "hoVaTen": "string",
    "tenHienThi": "string",
    "soDienThoai": "string",
    "ngaySinh": "2022-12-15T00:00:00",
    "soDu": 0,
    "chucVu": true
  }
]
```

In the expo (react-native) project:

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
        const url = `https://localhost:5001/api/NguoiDung`;
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(response.data);
};
```

However, when I use Axios in React Native to call the API, it displays an error:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
> [AxiosError: Network Error]

I have already set up CORS in ASP:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, 
                      options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader());
```

I have tried running it using the simulator and also connecting via Expo on my phone, but I cannot make the API call work.

Comment: Whether this issue only happens in the simulator? Try to test the web site in windows environment. According to your code, I create an API application and React application, it seems that the code works well on Windows environment, you can [check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHb81.png). Then, if the error only happens in the simulator, the issue might relate the request URL, **try to replace localhost with the IP address of your machine**, refer [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404).

Answer (score 0):

Try below line in `app` section. it work for my `mobile and Angular` projects.

```
app.UseCors(options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
```

It allows all domains to access from browsers.

Comment: Thanks you, but it not working for me